# upload files directly to folder

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a folder 'Files' in my project. How do I upload files directly to this folder?

I used the statements:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".\\File\\" + filename));
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its incorrect. You have to try this:

```
 FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("File//" + filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath` is root relative and in URI format, so use:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/File/" + filename));
```

Comment: It gives the error:
 Could not find a part of the path 'd:\Proj 1\Proj 1\Files\'.